# getting code in new line

Tags: jquery

I have several divs one of which is as below

```
<div id="drawarea">    
<img class="draggable ui-droppable ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging" id="image1"     src="user_2/1323384165.jpg" style="height: 40%; width: 50%; position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0%;">
<label id="first">This is content of the div</label>
<input type="button" value="GO"/>

</div>
```

I am using jquerys below function to get the html inside the div and put in a text area

```
 html = $('#drawarea').html();

$('#codearea').text(html);
```

the problem is that i am getting all the tags in same line i want to get one element code in one then others on other line so thats its easy to read.

Comment: Small aside, if its a text area you are putting this into, shouldn't you be using `.val` instead of `.text`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="drawarea">    
   <img class="draggable ui-droppable ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging" id="image1"     src="user_2/1323384165.jpg" style="height: 40%; width: 50%; position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0%;">
   <label id="first">This is content of the div</label>
   <input type="button" value="GO"/>
</div>
```

Here's the fix

```
rawhtml = $('#drawarea').html();
html = rawhtml.replace('<br />', /\n/g);
$('#codearea').text(html);
```

Comment: That'll just display the `<br/>` tags along with the rest, in the same one line, AFAIK.

Comment: I guess that's a solution, but if the OP's intent is do show the HTML code in the div, inside the `#codearea`, then this defeats the purpose and the code in the div and the code displayed in the codearea are no longer the same. But, I'll leave that to the OP.

Comment: not working for me. I want to show the code that i am getting from the drawarea in the codearea which is a text area

Comment: @ManBehind ,  Have made changes. I've tested it and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome 18/Windows XP this happens automatically, assuming that the HTML you're copying into the `textarea` has line-breaks between the elements:

```
$('#codearea').text($('#drawarea').html());​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AYUcN/5/)

Or, using `val()`:

```
$('#codearea').val($('#drawarea').html());​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AYUcN/4/)

It perhaps depends on your browser/platform, but to try and be sure I've set the CSS for the `textarea` to:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Which should enforce that behaviour, and prevent white-space from collapsing into a single space.